# EventBridge alerts not triggering with Service Catalog

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-event-bridge, aws-service-catalog

Attempted to implment EventBridge alerts that triggers an SNS notification whenever an event from Service Catalog (SC) is received/occurs. I tried the following event rules and patterns in terraform:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "servicecatalog_event_rule" {
  name        = "servicecatalog-rule"
  description = "Event rule to trigger SNS topic on Service Catalog events"

  event_pattern = <<EOF
  {
    "source": ["aws.servicecatalog"]
  }
  EOF
}
```

Pattern 2: API calls through CloudTrail (found this on the AWS management console).

```
{
  "source": ["aws.servicecatalog"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["servicecatalog.amazonaws.com"]
  }
}
```

SNS topic is also attached to a resource-based policy. This policy worked for CodePipeline events and ECS events. I am not sure if this is enough for Service Catalog or if it needs more access:

```
resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "servicecatalog_topic_policy" {
  arn = aws_sns_topic.servicecatalog_sns_topic.arn

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sns:Publish",
      "Resource": "${aws_sns_topic.servicecatalog_sns_topic.arn}"
    
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "servicecatalog_event_target" {
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.servicecatalog_event_rule.name
  target_id = "servicecatalog_event_target"
  arn       = aws_sns_topic.servicecatalog_sns_topic.arn
}
```

I have generated test events by doing actions in Service Catalog (such as provisioning a product or creating a portfolio) but the SNS was not still getting triggered in any of the attempts. Am I missing something? Does the policy need more access or is this an issue with Service catalog?

Comment: Are there any errors? If so, please add them to the question. Also, can you add `aws_cloudwatch_event_target` if you have that resource defined?

Comment: No errors anywhere, it just doesn't trigger the event rule. Added the resource.

Comment: Great. And have you taken a look at this example: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sns_topic_policy#example-usage?